# Decompress LZString in Ruby

Tags: python, php, ruby, compression

Is there any equivalent or open-source library for decompress using **LZ String** in Ruby ?

Code in Python :

```
x = lzstring.LZString()
decompress = x.decompressFromEncodedURIComponent("encrypted_data".decode('utf-8'))
```

Code in PHP :

```
\LZCompressor\LZString::decompressFromEncodedURIComponent("encrypted_data");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any equivalent or open-source library for decompress using LZ
> String in Ruby ?

According to [author of original (JavaScript) lz-string](https://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html)

> Here is a Ruby version, by Altivi:
>
> https://github.com/Altivi/lz_string

Comment: Hi, thx for the suggestion. I’ve tried this gem before, this gem doesn’t support decompressFromEncodedURIComponent. It’s only supoort Base64, Raw, and UTF-16

Comment: I’ve solved this problem by translate python’s library code to ruby syntax with the help of references from lz_string gem by Altivi.